# xcode 5 GM is mercilessly hanging all the time

Tags: macos, xcode5

I don't know what is going on, but I have downloaded xcode 5 gm and it is worse than dp 6.
It hangs when creating a brand new project. It hangs when I rename a class, and when trying to set up a local git repository.  It is a blank project master/detail template.

Does anyone have any idea what to do?  I have already deleted xcode 5 by dragging the app to the trash.

Is there anything I can do about this? I assume that I will want to remove all traces of xcode from my computer and retry again?  I'm on the latest mountain lion os.

Comment: I've also experienced this. It is definitely worse than DP6. Simulator is amazingly buggy and unstable.

Comment: I'm not experiencing this myself; not sure how to help. OS X 10.8.4; Xcode 5 (5A1412).

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I can only see Xcode 5 DP 6 available from the Apple Developer website, but I can see chatter about it in the forums. I'm guessing it's been pulled.</strike>

So the solution would be to delete Xcode 5 GM and continue using DP 6.

The reason I can only see Xcode 5 DP 6 is the fact that I didn't look on the Mac Developer Portal!

- Xcode 5 GM (now released) is for iOS 7 development and comes with the OSX 10.8 SDK.
- Xcode 5 DP 6 is for OSX 10.9 development and I am assuming this will become Xcode 5.1 when Mavericks (OSX 10.9) is released.

Therefore my above solution to remove Xcode 5 GM is wrong.